# Emulating process substitution using named pipes

Tags: c#, winapi, named-pipes

I'm trying to start a child process in .NET and redirect its output to a named pipe. Attempts to write to stdout in the child process should block until a client actually reads from the named pipe.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Pipes;

namespace psub
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pipeName = "testpipe"; // Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($@"\\.\pipe\{pipeName}");

            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "ping",
                Arguments = "google.com",

                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            };

            using (var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out))
            using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
            {
                pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                process.Start();
                process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(pipeServer);
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I start this executable, it blocks at `pipeServer.WaitForConnection();`, as expected. I then open a `cmd.exe` and run `type \\.\pipe\testpipe`, to attempt to read from the named pipe [1].

This results in the following error (in the cmd session):

```
All pipe instances are busy.
```

Moreover, in the C# program, `pipeServer.WaitForConnection` finishes, and execution proceeds to `...CopyTo(pipeServer)`, which explodes with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Pipe is broken.
```

I don't understand why the `All pipe instances are busy.` error is happening.

From my understanding there is a single server (instantiated in the C# program) that will write to the named pipe. Data will be ferried to the named pipe server on the program's single, blocked thread as soon as execution reaches `CopyTo`.

There is also a single named pipe client (the `type \\.\pipe\testpipe` process), which will relieve the named pipe of the data the server is trying to write.

So why then does the "All pipe instances are busy" error occur?

I've experimented unsuccessfully with adjusting `new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out)` to `new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out, 2)`, among other tweaks, but without any real understanding of what the problem is or how this would fix it. Could someone please explain it like I'm five?

---

[1]: The goal is to emulate the [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) feature available in UNIX shells, so it is essential that I be able to read from `\\.\pipe\<some file name>`, rather than using C++ or .NET to instantiate a client for the pipe.

Comment: `Pipe is broken` on write say about pipe handle has been closed already

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I understand that, but why did it die? The problem is the original `All pipe instances are busy.` error message, which results in the pipe dying, but why is it an error to read from the pipe at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `type <some_file_name>` in cmd - it first call `GetFileAttributes` for this `<some_file_name>`

[image]

the `GetFileAttributes` internal (inside kernel) temporary open file, for query it attributes (really - need query file-system device for this and for send query request - need open file).

for named pipe file this have fatal side effect - server end was connected (on open file) and just disconnected (on close).

only after this cmd (again) open file

[image]

but your pipe server already not listen (after disconnect). as result cmd usual receive `STATUS_PIPE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error - *An instance of a named pipe cannot be found in the listening state.* - it translated to win32 error `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY` - *All pipe instances are busy*

as separate note - 3 different status errors:

`STATUS_INSTANCE_NOT_AVAILABLE` (*The maximum named pipe instance count has been reached.*)

`STATUS_PIPE_NOT_AVAILABLE` (*An instance of a named pipe cannot be found in the listening state.*)

and `STATUS_PIPE_BUSY` translated to the same single win32 error `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`. but in your case original error was exactly `STATUS_PIPE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

conclusion - cmd `type` command not design to interact with pipes. or as alternative you need create how minimum 2 pipe ends on same pipe name.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. Is the `GetFileAttributes` call also the underlying factor in the `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY` I'm getting (perhaps both the `CreateFile` and `GetFileAttributes` are happening simultaneously)? I'll try setting up the server so it serves the file to an unlimited number of clients that connect within a timespan.

Comment: PS: could you please tell me what tool you used to trace the underlying windows API calls?

Comment: the error `STATUS_PIPE_NOT_AVAILABLE` is got *cmd.exe* on call `CreateFile`. it translate it to `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`. I use debugger. callstack in cmd.exe

Comment: with 2 running pipe ends on testpipe (with close just after write and start listen again on disconnect event) cmd correct print message with I write, however this is random. cmd not design to work with named pipes via type.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - however if you use redirected std handles instead `type` command - all worked well

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I'm seeing as well. `cat < \\.\pipe\foo` will work, but `cat \\.\pipe\foo` will not. This is unfortunate, because I'm trying to make an equivalent for bash process substitution, and need this to work with all windows executables that can accept a filename. I guess this kind of thing simply won't work generally on windows without emitting to a file.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - if executable design for work with std handles - you can use pipe here and all will be perfect worked if server code design well (enough single async pipe instance for both in-out). but if you pass *name* of pipe instead *handle* - here already can random work (for some programs) or not. pipe can be opened only once. first close - break connection (unlike usual file - not breaked on close). even query file attributes before open - break all.

Comment: If I follow the workaround I suggested above, where I simply start multiple pipe servers on different threads and replay the process output for all of them, it actually works. The problem is that I have another bug; doing `process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(pipeServer)` doesn't actually block threads in the child process that are trying to write to standard output, as I thought would be the case. I just get however much of the child process's output was available thus far emitted to the `type \\.\pipe\testpipe`.

Answer (score -2):

You have no access through command line interface for Windows named pipes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe for more info

Comment: This is wrong. I can easily create named pipes using [tools which directly work with the Windows API](https://github.com/psmay/windows-named-pipe-utils), and interact with them using `echo foo > \\.\pipe\foo` or `type \\.\pipe\foo`. A demonstration: https://i.imgur.com/vq6gwBd.gifv

Comment: On Windows, named pipes are connected to using the Win32 `CreateFile()` function, which is the most common way to open a file by name. It stands to reason that the `type` command of the Command Window would use `CreateFile()` to open a requested file, in which case it can also open a named pipe. This is also evident by the `busy` error message, which is an error that `CreateFile()` does report: "*If there is at least one active pipe instance but there are no available listener pipes on the server, which means all pipe instances are currently connected, CreateFile fails with ERROR_PIPE_BUSY.*"